# Calculating percentage in a glmer with a binomial family

Tags: r, percentage, glm

I would like to obtain the percentage of 96u yes of my three different conditions.

[image]

As you can see I'm working with this fit (because I'm working with binomial data)

```
fit96u=glmer(cbind(96u.yes,96u.No)~Condition+Type.eggs+(1|number),family=binomial(link=logit),data=data)
```

But which code should I use if I want to become the percentage of 96 u yes for every condition seperatly or/and combined with a type of egg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean think this is what you're looking for

```
library(dplyr)
percByCondition <- df %>% group_by(Condition) %>% summarize(percYes = mean(96u.yes))
```

where df denotes your input data frame.
If you want the frequencies grouped by type of egg or both condition and type of egg, you need to change the grouping variables accordingly in group_by()

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like

Construct "prediction frame", i.e. relevant combinations of predictors:

```
pframe <- with(my_data,
    expand.grid(Condition=levels(Condition),
                Type.Eggs=levels(Type.Eggs)))
```

Predict:

```
predict(fit96u,newdata=pframe,
          type="response",  ## predict on probability (not logit) scale
          re.form=~0)       ## ignore grouping when predicting
```

Alternatively, and for the predictions based only on Condition, check out the [lsmeans package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lsmeans) (don't forget `type="response"`:  [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148065/what-do-the-the-lsmeans-from-lsmeans-package-in-r-represent-when-calculated-ov))

Comment: It's more that I would like to count all the ones from 96.u Yes. After this I would like to devide it with the total numbers of observations (so the 0 and the 1 from 96.u Yes) (So I would obtain a percentage of all the ones in comparison to all the observation and this for the conditions and eggs separately)

Comment: then it sounds like you want something like @denise's answer?  Also, if this is the case, then I don't see what your fitted model has to do with it - aren't these just summary statistics that could be computed directly from the data?